# Q: VHDL Implementation of 2 simple funcitons

Tags: vhdl

I'm looking to implement the functions y = a and b; y = (a or b) and (c or d).

```
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity task1_tb is
--  Port ( ); end task1_tb;

architecture Behavioral of task1_tb is

--declaring the component   component task1
      Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC;
      b : in STD_LOGIC;
      y : out STD_LOGIC);   end component;

      signal y,a,b:     std_logic;
      signal counter:       unsigned(1 downto 0):="00";

begin       
    uut: task1 port map(a => a, b => b, y => y );

end Behavioral;
```

How can I assign a (bit 1) and b (bit 2) so it will test ever possible value and make a 20ns delay between each combination? I've been trying to learn VHDL these past two days for a school project and not even sure if what I have is right.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to use a `wait for <duration>` in your stimulus process.

```
process
begin
   for i in 0 to 2**2-1 loop --2**(number of input bits)-1
      (a, b) <= to_unsigned(i,2);
      wait for 20 ns;
   end loop;
   wait;
end process;
```

Credit to user1155120 for refinements.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail as to how this for loop is working? As in why 0 to 3? Also, if I want to assign results to y, would I just type "y<= i"?

Comment: 0 to 3 because you have 2 input bits, and 2**2 is 4 (0-3 is 4 values). I'll edit it to make it explicitly controllod by the counter width.  `y` is driven by your component instantiation; you don't want to drive it again. The results are already in `y`.

Comment: y already has a driver in the instantiated component, it's port y. There are four combinations of two inputs representing binary values. A loop executes the sequence of statements within it's body for every value of i, which is constant during those statements. 0 to 3 in binary maps all four combination of values, you could also: [use i directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9NCv.jpg) without a counter signal. The assignment to a and b is through an aggregate target (`(a, b )`) where the value of i is converted to an unsigned binary representation of the integer (natural) value of i.

Comment: @user1155120 aggregate targets can only be used in VHDL-2008 right?

Comment: No. Any revision.

Comment: That's great! I figured it was 2008 only since I've never seen it used in our codebase.

Comment: @user1155120 thanks for the info on the aggregate. Did not know it yet and haven't seen anybody use it. But in hindsight I think it would have simplified thinks on some occasions.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.1, -1987 8.3 Signal assignment statement target ::= name | aggregate. *If the target of the signal assignment statement is in the form of an aggregate, then the type of the aggregate shall be determinable from the context, excluding the aggregate itself but including the fact that the type of the aggregate shall be a composite type....* Unchanged in all that time. 9.3.3 *An aggregate is a basic operation (see 5.1) that combines one or more values into a composite value of a record or array type.*